# Prevent users from reusing compromised password

Tags: passwords

Suppose you store hashed and salted passwords, e.g. with Bcrypt. One day, you learn that user Bob's password has been compromised. You set his password to a strong, random string and notify him that he must reset his password. So far so good.

But Bob goes through the password reset process and types in the same, compromised password. Now his account is once again at the mercy of the attacker.

Can Bob be prevented from using the same password again? Without a salt, that would be straightforward. You could record the old, compromised hash and compare it against the hash of the new password Bob is attempting to enter. But with a salt, that doesn't seem feasible.

Is this an unsolvable problem?

**Edit:** I guess I was being silly. I'm not sure why I thought this was any different than checking the password at login. As martinstoeckli says, so long as you still have the old hash and salt, you can always compare the user's input against it.

Comment: You could store a handful of the previous pass hashes used and check their new password against that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the old compromised password hash, and do the same steps as you would do when verifying the password for the login. This also works with salted password-hashes, the situation is not different from the login verification.